# Express JS PUT not saving but it's updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express

I've an express JS application in which I'm trying to PUT(update an existing user's name). My schema is nested array and looks like this :

[image]

My code to update this user using PUT looks like this :

```
router.route('/sensors_update/:_id/')
    .put(function (req, res) {
        console.log("inside update put")
        User.findById(req.params._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(user);
            user.name = req.body.name;
            console.log("User val is" + user);
            user.save();
        });
    });
```

I'm able to clearly see the **user's name** is updating using the JS console. But I've issues when it comes to saving this user object. I guess this should be because I've a nested schema. Is my assumption right? Any suggestions regarding how to save an user object with nested arrays.

Here is the console message:

```js
inside update put
{ _id: 'Manasa',
  name: 'Manasa Sub',
  __v: 0,
  sensors: 
   [ { sensor_name: 'ras',
       _id: 57da0a4bf3884d1fb2234c74,
       measurements: [Object] } ] }
User val is{ _id: 'Manasa',
  name: 'Manas Sub',
  __v: 0,
  sensors: 
   [ { sensor_name: 'ras',
       _id: 57da0a4bf3884d1fb2234c74,
       measurements: [Object] } ] }
```

I was wondering why the nested array is accessed when I'm just trying to update&save the name of user.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

How can I solve this ?

Response :

```
    {
     "message": "Cast to date failed for value \"7:00\" at path \"time\"",
     "name": "CastError",
      "type": "date",
       "value": "7:00",
      "path": "time"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : push and set of mongodb does the trick when you've nested array.
that's the way to update a single field.

Answer (score 0):

Nested schema is not the issue. Error is clearly logged in the console. You are passing string type value for date type schema. Change the value of time from string type to date.

Or if you want to store string then change the time shcmea type from date to string.     time: {type: String}

Comment: This error occurs wheb you are trying to send response multiple times to the client. Make sure  it is correct in your route.

Comment: Console the err block of findById. It shouldn't throwing error.

Comment: I checked the routes and they look good with no duplicate sends.

Comment: if (err) { console.log(err);
res.send(err); } try this. It shouldn't be here.

Comment: I've pasted the response with the above description. I'm not sure how the time and stuff comes to play when I'm just updating the users name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125382/discussion-between-pink612-and-sachin).

Comment: When you are using save() it doesn't update only one filed, it just save the complete document and check all the validation on it. To update single field use update with $set.